# Drop column in compressed table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

is there any chance to drop a column in a compressed table?
I checked google and it seems like its not possible at all.

to get sure im asking here.

regards

Comment: What this of compression are you using? Offline block-level? Online? Columnar?

Comment: to be hones i have to idea :/

Comment: Check the COMPRESS_FOR attribute in DBA_TABLES to see what kind of compression is applied, then check for your specific Oracle version and that compression type.

Answer (score 1):

set that column to unused:

ALTER TABLE TEST SET UNUSED (column name);

ALTER TABLE TEST DROP unused columns;

Note: This statement does not actually remove the target column data or restore the disk space occupied by these columns. However, a column that is marked as unused is not displayed in queries or data dictionary views, and its name is removed so that a new column can reuse that name. All constraints, indexes, and statistics defined on the column are also removed.

If that does not work for you for some reason, you can try to move the table into a non-compressed format and then drop the column and compress again.